# to merge code of websphere and wildfly using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, wildfly, websphere-liberty

I have two code base for websphere and wildfly having same function name for both just some import statement as difference. For example for jax-rs
wildfly

```
hello()
{
ResteasyClient client= new Client();
//some code(abcdef)
ResteasyWebtarget target=new Webtarget();
//some code(xyz)
}
for Websphere
hello(){
Client client=new Client();
//some code(same as above code abcdef)
Webtarget target=new Webtarget();
//some code(same as above code xyz)
}
```

Similarly everything is same only this import is different in every function, case of wildfly and websphere. I want to merger the two code base to get one.
How to manage this with spring boot where when I select one environment as wildlfy in application.properties file I can run wildfly code with only wildfly pom.
In pom.xml I applied maven profile but if I activate ibm tag, the code shows error with wildfly part as in ibm activate there is no wildfly dependency.

Is there any way to solve it using spring boot (merging the code) or any other better way.

Comment: You can use @Profile in Spring Boot for such configuration. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: You can just use the WebSphere version as it is using straight JAX-RS API which should be supported by WildFly also. RestEasy is just one of the JAX-RS implementations, which adds a few methods and tries to make life easier, but they are not in spec. So just remove any resteasy code and switch to standard JAX-RS api and you will be good on any platform.